# How do I make project reference from another "project"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, project, project-reference

*Before I start, I did try to make an effort to search for answer, but nothing showed up.*

Scenario:  I created a .net standard library project (via the menu bar) and checked it in TFS.  Then, I created a Windows project that needs to use the .net standard library as reference.  **Anyone knows how I can accomplish this without copying the dll from the .net standard library project to the Windows project?**

Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure they're in the same solution, and use "add reference" in the normal way.

Comment: If the library is standalone, and potentially reusable in other projects, then you need to look up nuget packages and how to create them

Comment: add reference -> browse -> find the dll file and add it. Simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your reference as usual and then use browse to locate your dll.

[image]